# PHP simplexls - Getting column headings but no cell data

Tags: php

Running PHP v5.3.10 using the simplexls class v0.4 and after loading a spreadsheet the dimensions (i.e. rows and columns counts) are off.

The rows do contain the column headings but all of the data rows are empty even though there is data in the spreadsheet.

Following is a small sampling of output for illustrative purposes. Any ideas why I'm not getting any actual cell data?

```
Array
(
    [0] => cheyco.xlsx
)
Sheets count is: 7
i = 1:

Dimensions(1) returns:
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 5
)

Rows(1) returns:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Facility Code
            [1] => Site ID
            [2] => Name
            [3] => Description
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] =>
        )

)
i = 2:

Dimensions(2) returns:
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 29
)

Rows(2) returns:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Unit Code
            [1] => Facility Code
            [2] => Type (I,E,O)
            [3] => Name
            [4] => Description
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] =>
            [3] =>
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] =>
            [3] =>
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] =>
            [3] =>
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] =>
            [3] =>
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] =>
            [3] =>
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] =>
            [3] =>
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] =>
            [3] =>
        )
```

Comment: Could you please some post? And what is the simplexml class 0.4?

Comment: @dbf Your comment is nonsensical.

Comment: hmm it should have been, Could you please post some code? :)

Comment: +1 for clarifying what you mean by "the simplexml class v0.4". Is this a particular library you are using to process your spreadsheet? (SimpleXML is a built-in part of PHP, and nothing to do with spreadsheets)

Comment: My apologies but I meant SimpleXLS and not XML. I am trying to read a spreadsheet of data and process it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that SimpleXLS is not able to read the newer .xlsx format. Saving the document in the previous .xls format resolved the issue.